# Why doesn't this GridBagLayout code work?

Tags: java, swing, layout, gridbaglayout

I have the code below.

A similar code works. Also a friend said it *should* work. But it doesn't.

Anyone have a clue?

Thanks!

### Problem Description:

Instead of painting the desired layout, everything is tiny small... .(

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class ChatGUI extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3069354983197916315L;
    private Image imgBackground;

    private GridBagLayout gblChat;
    private GridBagConstraints constraintsChat;

    private JPanel jPanelChat;
    private JList clientList;

    private JColorChooser font_chooser;

    private JButton privateMessage_button;
    private JButton sendMessage_button;

    private JScrollPane OutputOfChatMessages;
    private JScrollPane ShowConnectedClients;
    private JScrollPane InputOfChatMessage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();

        ChatGUI cg1 = new ChatGUI(500, 500);

        jf.add(cg1);

        jf.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Layout
     */
    public ChatGUI(int width, int height) {

        // used for scaling
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width / 2,
                height / 4));
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width / 2,
                height / 4));

        jPanelChat = new JPanel();
        gblChat = new GridBagLayout();
        constraintsChat = new GridBagConstraints();

        this.setLayout(gblChat);
        this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        constraintsChat.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        /**
         * Panel 1 = OutputOfChatMessages
         */
        OutputOfChatMessages = new JScrollPane();

        constraintsChat.gridx = 0;
        constraintsChat.gridy = 0;
        constraintsChat.gridwidth = 1;
        constraintsChat.gridheight = 1;
        gblChat.setConstraints(OutputOfChatMessages, constraintsChat);

        this.add(OutputOfChatMessages);

        /**
         * Panel 2 = ShowConnectedClients
         */
        ShowConnectedClients = new JScrollPane();

        constraintsChat.gridx = 1;
        constraintsChat.gridy = 0;
        constraintsChat.gridwidth = 4;
        constraintsChat.gridheight = 4;
        gblChat.setConstraints(ShowConnectedClients, constraintsChat);

        this.add(ShowConnectedClients);

        /**
         * Panel 3 = InputOfChatMessage
         */
        InputOfChatMessage = new JScrollPane();

        constraintsChat.gridx = 0;
        constraintsChat.gridy = 5;
        constraintsChat.gridwidth = 2;
        constraintsChat.gridheight = 2;
        gblChat.setConstraints(InputOfChatMessage, constraintsChat);

        this.add(ShowConnectedClients);

        /**
         * Panel 4 = privateMessage_button
         */
        privateMessage_button = new JButton();

        constraintsChat.gridx = 1;
        constraintsChat.gridy = 6;
        constraintsChat.gridwidth = 1;
        constraintsChat.gridheight = 1;
        gblChat.setConstraints(privateMessage_button, constraintsChat);

        this.add(privateMessage_button);

        /**
         * Panel 5 = sendMessage_button
         */
        sendMessage_button = new JButton();

        constraintsChat.gridx = 1;
        constraintsChat.gridy = 7;
        constraintsChat.gridwidth = 1;
        constraintsChat.gridheight = 1;
        gblChat.setConstraints(sendMessage_button, constraintsChat);

        this.add(sendMessage_button);

        this.validate();
//this.revalidate();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your program?

Comment: Since there are no compiler errors and this is most probably a logical error, no.

Comment: So you haven't debugged your program. You don't need a compiler error to debug either.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. And how would the debugger have told me that I need to know to see the misakte?

Comment: For example; it could help you logically step through your program step-by-step until you are able to more clearly see the error occuring.

Comment: @Tdorno: Thanks for your input, but actually I am not sure if I would have recognized the problem without "MadProgrammer"'s help ;) 

Thanks anyway, James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You set no views for your scroll panes, therefore they have no means by which to determine their preferred size.
2. You set no text on your buttons, so it only calculates the size of the button on the requirements of the borders
3. Don't mess with `setXxxSize`, your `ChatGUI` should have no concept of the viewable size it might need to occupy.

Comment: @MadProfessor:

Yay, that did the track.

I have to check 1) tomorrow, to late for now. But 2) makes perfect sense, so all I can say is: DOH! This rly could have come to my mind... so thanks!

To 3): The size will be set by another class calling the chatGUI as a pane inside the main JFrame.

Anyway: Thanks!